# How to write if-else statement when column value is null in python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Daily, I am loading some files.
Each file is loading into 2 tables based on some filters.
For example Table1.C1 column values is null python script must go to second Table script.

```
cursor.execute("update Fact StagingTable1 set Flag=0 where C1 = ?", C1)
```

At the above line script is failing when C1 is null.

How to write the code?
Please help me.

This is the original script I used

```
import os, sys, time
import glob
import shutil
import os
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np
import pyodbc 

todaysdate = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")

folder_name ="C:\\Path"
dest =  "C:\\Path\\Archive\\"
file_type = ''
#all_Sales_files = sorted(glob.glob(folder_name + "/*Sales_*" ))
#all_Sales_files_sorted=sorted(os.listdir(folder_name))
file_titles = ['Col1']
os.chdir(folder_name)
all_Sales_files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(folder_name))
all_Sales_files = [os.path.join(folder_name, filename) for filename in all_Sales_files] # add path to each file
all_Sales_files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))

for filename in all_Sales_files:
    base = os.path.basename(filename)
    basewoe = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
    print(base + " File is started processing ...")

## File1 is processing into Table1  base on conditions
    df=pd.read_csv(filename, header=None,names=file_titles,low_memory=False)

#Loading script to load into Staging Table1
    C1=cursor.execute("select top 1 C1 from StagingTable1")
    C1_Result = cursor.fetchall()
    C1=[]
    for C1 in C1_Result:
        print(C1)
    cursor.execute("update Fact StagingTable1 set Flag=0 where C1 = ?", C1)  ## Here my script is faling
    sql_insert_query = "insert into FactTable1 select * from StagingTable1"
    cursor.execute(sql_insert_query)
    sql_conn.commit()

## File1 is processing into Table2 base on conditions

    df=pd.read_csv(filename, header=None,names=file_titles,low_memory=False)

Loading script to load into StagingTable2
Loading script to load into FactTable2

    shutil.move(filename, dest)
    print("Archiving "+ base +" file is successful...")
print("All files of Sales are successfully loaded into tables...")
```

Comment: What is the expected action when c1 is Null and what exact error are you getting? Did you use try and except statement. Also, in the code you have declared C1 as an empty list and then used the same variable to loop through C1_Result. Shouldn't you be using different variables.

Comment: If C1 is null then continue to run the program to load table2 as shown below:   ## File1 is processing into Table2 base on conditions

    df=pd.read_csv(filename, header=None,names=file_titles,low_memory=False)

Loading script to load into StagingTable2
Loading script to load into FactTable2

    shutil.move(filename, dest)
    print("Archiving "+ base +" file is successful...")
print("All files of Sales are successfully loaded into tables...